# Why doesn't Windows 8.1 accelerometer API output data when device is motionless?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, accelerometer

I'm playing with the C++ accelerometer API in WinRT on a Windows 8.1 ultrabook. I'm surprised to find that the API only updates the accelerometer data when the device is in motion. If it's sitting still on a table, the accelerometer readings do not update. I tried both polling and subscribing to updates by adding an event handler to Accelerometer.ReadingChanged. When the device is motionless, the event handler does not get called. When polling while the device is motionless, I continuously get the same old data, with the same old timestamp. Here is some sample data, polled at 16ms intervals.

```
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
130724777430758219  accel   x: -0.005   y: -0.836   z: -0.728
```

The timestamp is the first column. You can see that the timestamp does not change. I would expect the acceleration data to not change, but am surprised that the timestamp does not change. This is not how it works on other platforms (iOS, Android). I expect to see different timestamps on each sample even if the device is motionless. This leads me to suspect that Windows might be doing some filtering on the data.

Does anyone know if this behavior is intended in Windows 8.1? Could it be specific to just my device model? Is Windows doing any filtering of the accelerometer data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Windows is indeed filtering the accelerometer data. There is a COM API called [ISensor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that allows you to get unfiltered data. Unfortunately, it's not the nicest API, nor is it well documented. Here's a [sample app](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/windows-8-sensors-sample-application-a-ball-in-hole-game) that illustrates it's use. Note that in order to get unfiltered data, you have to [set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the sensor's [SENSOR_PROPERTY_CHANGE_SENSITIVITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to 0. The sample app does not show this.